# Child class as abstract class in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following code in my program

```
public abstract class test
    {
        public abstract void test1();
        public abstract void test2();
       public abstract void test3();
    }
    public abstract class class1 :test
    {

      public  override void test1()
        {
            string s = "";
        }
    }
```

When I change the type of my child class as abstract it build successfully and the error to include the other two methods have gone.  if the child class is abstract class, no need to define at least one abstract methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mark a method as `abstract` it means that every (concrete) class which inherits it must provide an implementation - it's a contract in a similar way to interface implementation is a contract.

If you mark the child class as `abstract` also, it means that it can defer implementation to *its child class(es)*.

Comment: but as long as it have no child class, it should not compile right? Also this will allow static methods which can be called from other classes. then what is the point of having abstract class?

Comment: @user1357872 im sorry i dont understand the first question in your comment, but to answer the last, the point of abstract classes are much the same as the point of interfaces - with the addition that you can write *some* implementation into an abstract class but none into an interface.

Answer (score 1):

It compiles fine, because the child class is *abstract* too.

That means that in order to instantiate an object of that type, you still need to have yet a third class (at least) that inherits from your child class and that implements the full interface (the missing abstract methods from your parent class).

The class hierarchy that you have presented, cannot be instantiated until there is a class that implements all the required methods - that would be something that can be instantiated.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not neccessary, as it's fine for an abstract class to contain just method headers, and the other method headers from the abstract base class get inherited.

Comment: Eh. Abstract classes can also contain implementations.

Comment: @DigiFriend can, but don't have to. They *can* also contain just method headers ;) I clarified my post.

Answer (score 0):

No - you can declare a class abstract without having any abstract methods. It may not make any sense conceptually for an instance of that class to exist, or you may want to ensure that only subclasses of that class can be instantiated (for whatever reason)